# make this php script echo before fully executed

Tags: php

I did follow the buffering advice but I still didn't get it to work. here is my code. I am trying to only let a button selecting a row from the database one time each 2 hours. So my goal is to display the table echo before the script waits 2 hours. I am trying to:

Let php check if row inside table verification is yes or no.
if it is yes then proceed to select a row from another table
after selecting that row wait 2 hours then edit the row from the other table to no
else if the row inside table verification is no then display a message to the user that he has to wait.

By this I want if 2 hours has passed, to let the user get what he wants from the database else display him the message. As I said I created another table where the row verify varies from yes to no. If it is yes it should let the user get what he wants else no.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
$link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'DATABASEUSERNAME', 'DATABASEPASSWORD', 'DATABASE' );  
$query4 = "SELECT * FROM verification WHERE verify='yes'";
$verify = mysqli_query($link, $query4) or die("Error");
$rowcount2 = mysqli_fetch_array($verify);
if ($rowcount2['verify'] == 'yes') {
        $query="SELECT * FROM daily LIMIT 1";
        $show = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error");
        echo "<p id='paragraph' style='font-size:22px;font-weight: bold;'>Here is your info:</p>";
        ob_flush();
            flush();   
        echo "<table style='position:relative;bottom:30px;' border='2px'><tr><td>val1</td><td>val2</td></tr>";
        ob_flush();
        flush();   
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['val1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['val2'] . "</td></tr>";
            ob_flush();
                flush();   
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ob_flush();
            flush();   
        $query2="UPDATE verification SET verify='no' WHERE verify='yes'";
        $update = mysqli_query($link, $query2);
        sleep(10); // this should be 2 hours but I am only testing the script for now.
        $query3="UPDATE verification SET verify='yes' WHERE verify='no'";
        $update = mysqli_query($link, $query3);
} else {
    echo "false";
    ob_flush();
        flush();   
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow, this is a really horrible-designed code. What about using OOP?

Comment: That is the most simple solution I found to do this since I don't have a lot of knowledge in php and I am a beginner.

Comment: Ok, I strongley recommend to start learning proper OOP as a "beginner"

Comment: PHP by default, without output buffering, will echo as it is run.  (Try running this as CLI without ob to see).  It is the web server API that needs configuring.  For example, mod_php won't output until PHP finishes executing.   Due to web server limitations, most people choose to run scripts like this in the background.

Comment: @bub hey man, when I started with PHP language, my code looked similarly. I started to learn OOP, when I better understood PHP (at first, I created functions, then I created classes, etc). I mean, that PHP OOP may be hard to understand for some beginners.

Comment: @pes502 That is why you need the right advices as a beginner or you waste yours and others time

Comment: No one provided an answer to this question. Further research show that I should flush large amount of data in order for it to work. ( more than 256 bytes ). But I don't know how to do this.